# Will after i batch restore on titanium backup will it restore to the same location?

Tags: backup, restore, titanium-backup

I have done a backup with titanium backup (except system apps) More I am switching to another ROM. 
My question is when I will batch restore then will my internal apps(apps not installed in SD card ,installed on phone storage) that I have installed will be restored to same location as of previous ROM?ie . internal apps to internal and SD card apps to SD card.

Switching to same ROM version android 4.1.2 JellyBean

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Don't worry. It usually restore in the same location. Even if it doesn't it isn't supposed to cause problems. You can always move them.